# ¿cómo guardar un archivo de texto con un nombre especificado por mi?

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de obtener la ruta de un archivo.txt y al cargar el archivo y guardarlo en la misma ubicación pero con otro nombre "respuestas.txt" con las operaciones que realizo.

Dándome un resultado así.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI4Xn.png

Y no encuentro la forma para que se guarde solamente con el nombre "respuestas.txt"

Espero alguien me pueda apoyar, gracias.

public class Peticion {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Http peticion = new Http();
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

    FileNameExtensionFilter txt = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Archivos de texto", "txt","text");
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(txt);
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);

    String ruta = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    String nombreArchivo = "respuestas.txt";
    File file = new File(ruta+nombreArchivo);
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    String line = "";
    String cad = "";

    try {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(ruta));
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            line = input.nextLine();
            cad += line + "\n" + peticion.getHTTP(line) + "\n\n";
        }

        if(file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(cad);
        bw.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File archivoSeleccionado = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
//aquí ya tenemos el archivo que se seleccionó.

File directorio = archivoSeleccionado.getParentFile();
//aquí ya tenemos el directorio del archivo seleccionado

File archivoNuevo = new File(directorio, "respuesta.txt");
//aquí ya tenemos el archivo nuevo en el directorio de donde se obtuvo el seleccionado.
```

Comment: Me sirvió así, ya que en las opciones del constructor del Scanner no me dejaba pasandole directamente el directorio File archivoSeleccionado = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        String archivoSeleccionado2 = archivoSeleccionado.toString();
        File archivoNuevo = new File(archivoSeleccionado.getParentFile(),"respuestas.txt");

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Http peticion = new Http();
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

        FileNameExtensionFilter txt = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Archivos de texto", "txt","text");
        fileChooser.setFileFilter(txt);
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);

        String ruta = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        String nombreArchivo = "respuestas.txt";

        //ORIGINAL:  File file = new File(ruta+nombreArchivo);
        /*Cambio...*/File file = new File(ruta, nombreArchivo);


        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        String line = "";
        String cad = "";

        try {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(ruta));
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                line = input.nextLine();
                cad += line + "\n" + peticion.getHTTP(line) + "\n\n";
            }

            if(file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(cad);
            bw.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```